# Office 365 Mail App compose mode - Unable to get email body content in outlook desktop client

Tags: javascript, office365, office-addins

I am unable to get body content in compose mode when i run my mail app in outlook desktop client. But, I am able to get body content when i access my app in outlook web either in IE or Chrome or FF browsers. Can anybody help me what could be the issue here? Kindly refer to attached screen shot.

[image]

FYI, i am using 1.1 version of Office.js and here is my code snippet to read body content.

```
function getBody() {
    Office.cast.item.toMessageCompose(Office.context.mailbox.item).body.getAsync(function (result) {
        app.showNotification('The current body is', result.value)
    });

    //Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.MailboxEnums.BodyType.Html, function (result) {
    //    app.showNotification('The current body is', result.value)
    //})
}
```

Comment: What version of desktop Outlook are you using?

Comment: I am using Outlook 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getAsync` method on the Body was introduced in Mailbox version 1.3, which isn’t supported by Outlook 2013. It is supported by Outlook 2016, which is currently in preview. If you want to try it out you can download the preview here: https://products.office.com/en-us/office-2016-preview.

EDIT: In addition, there's one code change you need to make. The `getAsync` method was updated so that the `coercionType` parameter is mandatory now. MSDN has not been updated yet with this change. So you'd need to change your code to:

```
Office.cast.item.toMessageCompose(Office.context.mailbox.item).body
  .getAsync("text", function (result) {
    app.showNotification('The current body is', result.value)
  });
```

Comment: Im using the Outlook 2016 on windows 10 , and when Im trying to getBody with correctionType HTML it passes to me unkown symbols, but with tyep TEXT it passes normal text, what's goes wrong ? should I open issue for that ? on web browsers it works properly